# Getting null when trying to send Email via Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, email

I have javascript function to sendEmail like:

```
function sendEmail() {
    var appweburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    var fieldName = "Notificar a";
    var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
    var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
    var _sid ="";
    if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
        _sid = _sid = $(emailSpan).attr('sid');
        _sid = _sid.split("|")[2];
    } else {
        alert("null");
    }

    var fieldUsuario = _sid;    
    
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': 'gmc@gmc.onmicrosoft.com',
                'To': { 'results': [fieldUsuario] },
                'Body': 'Hello',
                'Subject': 'remember'
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.results;
            var i = result.length;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

Problem occurs whenn it reach success function, data always come undefined:

[image]

Sources: [How to Send Email By Javascript](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19df75c4-e708-4ea2-8c92-93b7c9e84817/how-to-send-email-by-javascript-in-sharepoint-online-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Some ideas why it comes null? Regards

Comment: are you adding multiple values in People Picker field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be receiving emails but in **Junk Mail** folder.
So You have to pass all the attributes e.g **Body, Subject, To, From** as a variable rather than static.

**Please check the updated code below :**

```
function sendEmail() {

var appweburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";


var fieldName = "Notificar a";
var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
var _sid ="";
if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
         _sid = _sid = $(emailSpan).attr('sid');
     _sid =  _sid.split("|")[2];
} else {
       alert("null");
}

        var fieldUsuario = _sid;
        var fromMail = 'gmc@gmc.onmicrosoft.com';
        var subject = 'remember ';
        var body = 'Hello';    

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': fromMail,
                'To': { 'results': [fieldUsuario] },
                'Body': body, 
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.results;
            var i = result.length;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: one important question.. What should be my onmicrosoft  from Email? Whatever I want?

Comment: yes, You can add any SharePoint registered user email address as From user, those emails will be sent from that mentioned user.

Comment: Another question sir, If I want to send value to multiple users, I change `fieldUsuario` for array into `'To'`, so my array is like `user1@onmicrosoft.com, user2@onmicrosoft.com` , they are correctly separatted by commas or they need to separated by `;`